# How my JS function would restrict specific data ?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In asp.net textbox I have called a javascript function which I wrote to restrict only 'digits' entry in text box but I also want to allow '+' sign but can't solve it.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                return false;

            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse your condition and add the ASCII code for `+` which is `43` to return `true`

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
            if ((charCode >=48 && charCode <= 57) || (charCode == 43))
                return true;
            return false;
       }
```

Comment: Great ! worked but why reversing the conditions sir ?

Comment: Its the optimization for your code :) please accept if it helped

Answer (score 1):

If you were able to restrict digits, you can also enter '+', I guess you need ASCII table and corresponding value i.e. how you were restricting digits, and `charCode > 31` seems useless if you are checking for digits only:
http://www.asciitable.com/

so if you want to check for +

```
charCode != 43
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `+` as well explicitly, modify your if to :

```
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 43)
```

Here is working example:

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 43) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="extra7" name="extra7" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm2hS/2659/)

[Ascii Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

```
function isNumber(evt) {
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)&& charCode != 43) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```